# Nhibernate DetachedCriteria: Find entities where a property's property match a value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, nhibernate, detachedcriteria

I have two following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    // other stuff

    protected User() { }
}

public class UserCredentials
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    // other stuff

    protected UserCredentials() { }
}
```

I want to create a detached criteria that finds all users where `Credentials.UserName = "someuser"`, but I cannot get it right.. I have tried the following:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<User>().Add(Expression.Eq("Credentials.UserName", "someuser");
```

but I get an exception saying

> "could not resolve property:
>   Credentials.UserName of:
>   DataLinkNord.Domain.User"

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue before myself (although I'm a Java user), but the way around it for me was to use the "addAlias()" call first... something like:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<User>().AddAlias("Credentials", "Credentials").Add(Expression.Eq("Credentials.UserName", "someuser");
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but I think I need to revisit my mappings, because I get an invalid SQL expression where it tries to join the User table with itself..